# cocos2d: how to create a spritsheet animation from png file

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

You see, I am new to cocos2d and I'd like to do some explosion animation for the game I am currently developing. I found a free explosion sprites such as this website http://percsich.hu/tgmforum/index.php?topic=446.0 However, I don't know how to create a sprite sheet from that .png picture in the previous link... How can I do that with keeping the transparency of the sprite file and the correct size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a tool like one of these:

- [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)
- [Zwoptex](http://www.zwopple.com/zwoptex/)

They both have free versions you can try before you buy one.

If you need a utility to crop images, I suggest GIMP:

- [GIMP on OS X](http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html)

Comment: Hi, I have already downloaded TexturePacker. However, I don't think it allows cropping the image

Comment: @Wabbit Added a link to image processing software that can crop for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with getting pre-packaged sprite sheets is that you will have to manually create the boundaries for the sprites (the bounding rectangles).  You don't get the data file with it.

The usual method for creating a sprite sheet is to take a sequence of images and put them into the "tool" (Zwoptex or Texture Packer are both excellent; I favor Texture Packer).  The tool produces the sprite sheet, and also produces the .plist (or whatever you need) file which identifies all the locations for the sprites in the sprite sheet.  In cocos2d, you load the sprite sheet and the sprite sheet data file (.plist).

Then you can reference the names from code to load them (or if you are clever, name them so you can automatically probe for them in sequence and automatically load them with a single key).

Given the sprite sheet you have, you can use something like Gimp to cut them up into small images, then add them to your "sprite sheet creation tool" and go from there.

If you would like a way to create all the fireballs (or other particle effects you could want) such as the one below, automatically, and dump them to files so you can just drop them into a sprite sheet tool, [see this article](http://nonlinearideas.com/particle-system-slide-creator/) (with code on [github](https://github.com/NonlinearIdeas/ParticleSlideCreator)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.tpacker.com](http://www.tpacker.com) it create animations from sprite sheets with simple drag & drop method. Hope it helped.